# Accessing control which is in ListView InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a LinkButton in listview InsertItemTemplate. Whose visibility i want to set from code behind. I am using this code, but it seems on applying breakpoint that the control is not reaching InsertItemTemplate. It just stays within ItemTemplate.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserId"].ToString() == Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString())
    {

        foreach (ListViewItem item in lvAlbums.InsertItem.Items)
        {
            LinkButton linkButton = item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
            if (linkButton != null)
                linkButton.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Source code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListView ID="lvAlbums" runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GroupItemCount="3" 
            InsertItemPosition="LastItem">            
            <LayoutTemplate>                
                    <table border="1">
                       <tr ID="groupPlaceholder" runat="server">
                       </tr>
                    </table>                       
            </LayoutTemplate>                                              
            <GroupTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
             </GroupTemplate>             
             <ItemTemplate>
                    <td id="Td3" width="150px" height="150px" align="center" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPhotoID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DefaultPhotID") %>' />
                    <a href='<%# "Photos.aspx?AlbumID="+Eval("AlbumID") %>'> 
                    <asp:Image CssClass="Timg" runat="server" ID="imPhoto" ImageUrl='<%# "ThumbNail.ashx?ImURL="+Eval("Photo") %>' />
                    </a>
                    <br />                    
                    <b><asp:Label ID="lblAlbumName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AlbumName") %>'></asp:Label>   </b>
                    </td>                
                </ItemTemplate>

                <InsertItemTemplate>
                <td id="Td3" width="150px" height="150px" runat="server" align="center" style="background-color: #e8e8e8;color: #333333;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/CreateAlbum.aspx"> Create New Album1</asp:LinkButton>
             <%--   <a href="CreateAlbum.aspx" id="createalbumlink" runat="server">                    
                    Create New Album
                </a>--%>
                </td>              
                </InsertItemTemplate>             
            </asp:ListView>

        &nbsp;<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SLIITComDBConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where album.userid=@userid">
       <SelectParameters>
       <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userid" Type="int32"  QueryStringField="id" />

         <%--<asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" Type="String"  SessionField="UserId" />--%>
</SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Access and modify the LinkButton in ItemTemplate of listview in [ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemdatabound.aspx) instead of `page_load`</strike>

```
protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label EmailAddressLabel;
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        LinkButton linkButton = e.item.FindControl("LinkButton1") as LinkButton;
        if (linkButton != null)
            linkButton.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit**, based on comments. You can hide the InsertItem or controls within it on Page_Load.

**Hiding particular control in InsertItem template**

---

As you are trying to hide all items in InsertItemTemplate, you can access the InsertItem Template and find control in it using FindControl. You have LinkButton in InsertItem template with id `LinkButton1`, you can hide it by first finding in InsertItem

```
((LinkButton)lvAlbums.InsertItem.FindControl("LinkButton1")).Visible = false;
```

**Hiding whole InsertItem template**

---

You can completely hide the `InsertItem` template using `InsertItem` `Visible` property.

```
lvAlbums.InsertItem.Visible = false;
```

Comment: I tried your code.. by adding 

        
        if (Session["UserId"].ToString() == Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString())
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    
   but it still did not work

Comment: breakpoint wont apply on protected void ContactsListView_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)

Comment: Check if you bind the ContactsListView_ItemDataBound in the html

Comment: its lvAlbums_ItemDataBound actually(i renamed it) and its bound to database. I want to check session value and value of the querystring , if they match then i do not want insertitemtemplate to appear. I added a button and on buttonclick event i wrote lvAlbums.InsertItem.Visible = false; 
 and it worked just fine. Hiding the insertitemtemplate on page load would solve my problem.